# Xcode: Color highlight code/text on cursor blinking

Tags: xcode, automator

In Android/Eclipse, if I single click on a word, all of its occurrences are **color** highlighted throughout the file.

Is the same possible in Xcode?

Is there a plugin for achieving it?

Is there any **Automator Script/Service** to achieve this ?

Comment: Currently xcode underlines all occurances with a dotted line.  I would be a fan of more noticable highlighting as well, but you can double click, copy, find, paste and that will highlight them all.  Other than that I'm still looking for a solution to this with you.

Comment: @Putz1103:Thanks for the reply. I am aware of it. But I am looking for color highlighting as in Eclipse.

Comment: FYI: In Xcode 9, when I click in a word, other instances in the file are also highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode click into the word and then hover over it and you should see a little dropdown arrow appear to the right of the word. Click this arrow and choose 'edit all in scope'. This will highlight all occurrences in the file... and let you edit them all at once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of it. But I am looking for **color highlighting** as in Eclipse.